# Searching And Selecting a TreeView Item programmatically?

Tags: c#, wpf, treeview, treeviewitem

In my 3d application, I have a `TreeView` that is databound to an `ObservableCollection` of objects in my 3d scene. In theory a user can click on an object in the 3d view, which should update the `TreeView` to select the corresponding item. But I don't exactly know how. All I have is the 3d object the user picked.

How do I go about doing this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Found the solution right [here](http://blog.quantumbitdesigns.com/2008/07/22/programmatically-selecting-an-item-in-a-treeview/).

http://blog.quantumbitdesigns.com/2008/07/22/programmatically-selecting-an-item-in-a-treeview/

And he's got sample source code that works, which kicks all kinds of ass.

Answer (score -2):

I would assume both the treeview and scene item would share ( and be identified by ) a common ID value.  Then, in either your 3D scene or Treeview, implement and subscribe to an OnSelectionChanged, which your TreeView probably already has.  Then, when one is updated/changed, the other should be notified instantly, and update itself accordingly.  Be sure of course to eat the change even on the update or you will create a nasty loop of OnChange events.

... or, did I misunderstand your question?